# In actionscript 3 flash cs5, how do I define a symbol's position

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, position, flash-cs5

I wan to know how to move a movie clip to a certain x, y. How would I do that? Because I know this is wrong:

```
paddle.x = 253;
```

Thanks.

Comment: I am using an accelerometer and I dont want the number to go past 253 and if it does, I want to say: paddle.x = 253;

Comment: Actually if your movieclip has the instance name "paddle", what you are doing is completely correct.

Comment: Thank you all. I just realized it was a different part of code that messed it up

Answer (score 0):

check that the name of the movieclip is "paddle" not(or not just) the class name.

Also make sure that you put this code in the parent

Answer (score 0):

To move any DisplayObject or MovieClip you can use Tween Class to animate. and you can also use timeline based Animation.
Using Tween Class to move paddle movieClip in 3 seconds
then here is the code

vat TweenObj:Tween =new Tween(paddle, "x", Elastic.easeInOut,paddle.x, 254, 3, true);

Answer (score 0):

Check that the movieclip you are trying to move is currently placed on the stage and that it is named (in the properties) paddle. Then `paddle.x = 253;` should work as long as the actionscript is on the same frame